# Grails: Eliminating ConfigurationHolder from custom validator in domain class

Tags: grails, dns, validation

I have a custom validator in a domain class that refers to a config property:

```
accountExpirationDate (
    nullable:true,
    validator: { val, obj ->
        if (val > new Date() + CH.config.EXPIRATION_WINDOW_DAYS) return ['date_too_late']
    })
```

where CH is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder

Since ConfigurationHolder is deprecated, I need to get rid of it. I have tried using grailsApplication in its place but it does not work in this instance. Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a dependency injection for `grailsApplication`, and then you can access that from the `obj` instance

```
class MyDomainClass {

   def grailsApplication

   Date accountExpirationDate

   static constraints = {
      accountExpirationDate(nullable:true, validator: { val, obj ->
         def config = obj.grailsApplication.config
         if (val > new Date() + config.EXPIRATION_WINDOW_DAYS) return ['date_too_late']
      })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new getDomainClass method in the domain. You can try to use this to access the grailsApplication.

```
validator: { val, obj ->
    if (val > new Date() + this.getDomainClass().grailsApplication.config.EXPIRATION_WINDOW_DAYS) return ['date_too_late']
})
```

Here is a better coverage about the the topic: 
http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=993

Comment: Yes, that's where I saw it. I also added the link to my answer for it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that the getDomainClass() is new to Grails 2.0, and I omitted to mention that I'm still on 1.3.7.